# Play spotify track using URI

Tags: ios, objective-c, spotify

```
-(void)playSpotifyTrack:(NSURL*)playURI trackDuration:(float)duration {

    id sessionData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SpotifyOAuthSession"];
    self.spotifySession = sessionData ? [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:sessionData] : nil;

    [self.spotifyPlayer loginWithSession:self.spotifySession callback:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"*** Logging in got error: %@", error);
            return;
        }

        [self.spotifyPlayer playURIs:@[ playURI ] fromIndex:0 callback:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"*** Starting playback got error: %@", error);
                return;
            }
        }];
    }];

    [self startSeekBar:duration];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
}
```

i had write above code to play spotify track but not able to play spotify track.some time it gives error no Refresh token.
https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/issues/548